# The C# project is targeting ".NeETFramework, Version=v4.0", which is not installed on this machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Trying to run an old project in Visual Studio 2015.  It was created in 2012 or 2013, I cannot remember which.  I have uninstalled both programs as I was running out of space, and i think that is what caused this.  I get the following options:

[image]

And I do not want to change the target, so clicking on the second option brings me to https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting which I can't seem to find anything there that remedies the situation.  Is there a way around this without reinstalling the old version of Visual Studio again?  Will that even fix my problem?  Thank you.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding what your trying to achieve, but visual studio itself isnt specifically tied to a framework. check if you still have .net 4.0 installed and if so you might want to repair your vs 2015 otherwise. Here is the stadalone installer https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Reinstall Visual Studio. When you uninstalled previous version it caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a repair reinstall of Visual Studio 2015.

Another point to consider is that Windows 7 (the oldest version of Windows still supported by Microsoft) includes a Windows Update for the .NET Framework v4.6.1 categorized as an "Important" update. I have not confirmed with Windows 8, but I suspect it, too, includes a similar update. Windows 10 comes with .NET 4.6 to start with. That means that any up-to-date supported machine today will be able to run apps targeting any .NET version up to and including 4.6. I recognize that there may be other reasons to continue targeting an older .NET version, but I bring this up just in case the concern is support on client workstations.